# Function to check for value prior to using getValue?

Tags: entities

I'm trying to write a function that takes into account both regular text fields and entity references and checks for a value prior to using getValue() to assign it to a variable.

```
   function checkUserFieldAvailability($fieldName, $assignedName){
      if (!$user->get($fieldName)->isEmpty()) {
        ${$assignedName} = $user->get($fieldName)->first()->getValue()['target_id'];
      }
      else {
        ${$assignedName} = "";
      }
    }
```

Something like this... Is there an easy way to make it account for both entity references that are assigned like this...

```
$name = $user->get('field_firstname')->first()->getValue()['target_id'];
```

and regular text fields which are assigned like this.

```
$email = $user->get('mail')->getValue();
```

Basically i'm trying to confirm all the fields I'm making assignments too in fact first have a value (to avoid errors) and if not assing  an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the main property of the field:

```
if ($item = $user->get($fieldName)->first()) {
  $string = $item->{$item->mainPropertyName()};
}
else {
  $string = '';
}
```